# Customer registration form edit (customized field not update while editing) in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, customization, magento-1.8

Two extra fields added to magento customer registration.The valued saved in the database and i can retrieve the value, while editing the form the edited value not saved in the database.
Anyone can give me a solution or please help me to find out my wrong?

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you add the two fields in form. I mean,

- Did you create a module to override customer module?
- Added two customer attributes from in database from your module
- Override customer account controller or written an observer class function to save values of those two fields.

If not then please explain your process first.

Comment: 1.Add new field to config.xml in customer account scope. 2.add below code segment to register.phtml to create the database fields $setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup'); $setup->addAttribute('customer', 'mobileno', array( 'label' => 'Mobile No', 'type' => 'varchar', 'input' => 'text', 'visible' => true, 'required' => true, 'position' => 1, )); 3.add relevant fields in to register.phtml and edit.phtml to view the saved data i used this below code echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getCustomer()->getMobile()); my Magento version is 1.9 Thank you

Comment: You have added attribute as 'mobileno' and you are trying to get value as echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getCustomer()->getMobile()); instead of echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getCustomer()->getMobileno()); 

May be this is the issue. Also check the field name which you are saving.

Comment: Thank you Mohith :).
i created the attribute under customer scope and try to retrieve it in the customer_addrees scope.this was the error for me.
now its Work fine.Do u have any idea about adding a checkbox for multiple selection?
Thanks in Advance....